# I want to cancel my vote

Tags: support

I upvoted a post mistakenly. Then I tried to cancel my vote but I couldn't because my reputation isn't enough. How can I cancel my vote?

Comment: Learn to live with it. It is very far from a tragedy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cancel a vote by re-clicking the arrow for that vote, which you have the rep for that vote. That is, you cancel a upvote by clicking the up-arrow again. And the rep limit for that is the same as for casting the vote in the first place.

It sounds like you tried to cast a downvote which is a separate action.

That said, there is a time limit for canceling votes. After 5 minutes (I think) you won't be able to cancel that vote unless the post has been edited in the mean time.

Comment: Thank you dear dmckee. You right. Now what can I do?

Comment: @lucas Do better next time ;)

Comment: @lucas There is not much you can do but hope that the post is edited. We generally discourage people from making or proposing edits just so that they can reverse a vote. On the other hand, one  misplaced vote is not a tragedy in the long run, so don't fret it.

Comment: @ But that post was wrong. Any way, thanks a lot.